# TextBox.TextChanged event not firing on IE7

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-7

In my web form I have a `Textbox` control. The `TextChanged` event of the `Textbox` is not triggering.
`AutoPostBack` is set to `true`

What could be the reason for this?
Here is the code:

```
protected void Textr_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

}

<asp:TextBox ID="Textr" TabIndex="10" Style="z-index: 117; left: 500px;
                            position: absolute; top: 158px" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="180px" MaxLength="50"
                            AutoPostBack="True"   CausesValidation="true"   OnTextChanged="Textr_TextChanged" 
                          ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I assume you have hooked the event to the textbox by doing something like _textBox.TextChanged += TextSerialNumber_TextChanged; ?

Comment: Is it working in other browsers?

Comment: its working in mozilla, others i haven't tried

Comment: CausesValidation="false" ValidationGroup="__mygroup"

Answer (score 1):

Are there any validation controls on the form along with this textbox? I see you have causesvalidation explicitly set to true (which I believe is the default state).  Try removing that and see if it fires.  If the postback is hung up on a validation control, your event handler will not fire.

My two cents.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem just after adding a standard HTML Input control somewhere else in the document. After this, the TextBox1.TextChanged stopped working.

My solution was to put the textbox into a span with an onclick event ensuring a postback by means of an invisible button like this:

=========

## Original:

{asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" /}

=========

## Solution:

{span onclick="document.getElementById('btn_ToForcePostback').click();"}

{asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" /}

{/span}

{asp:Button ID="btn_ToForcePostback" runat="server" text="" style="width:0px; height:0px"/}

---

(The { and } should be changed to "smaller than" and "larger than" character)

Answer (score 0):

Is it working in rest browsers? Don't forget that this event is fired then control is loosing focus. :) Try to click outside of textbox after inputing.

Comment: Yes try to have 2 TextBoxes and change the one with the event and Tab out of it to the next TextBox. See if this fires the event or not.

Comment: I have IE8, I'm using IE7 emulation feature and it is working well for me. Do you have testing code? Can you share it?

Answer (score 0):

it may be messed up by some javascript you are using on the same page, or else you can make sure yourself if it is IE7 problem or not by making a sample for this. Very high level it looks like sonething related to javascript mess up.